# jquery on mousedown does not select parent

Tags: javascript, jquery, right-click, mousedown

i've got an issue with my function. 
This is my example markup:

```
<div id="parent">
   <div id="container">
      <div id="childElement1">
      </div>
      <div id="childElement1">
      </div>
   <div>
</div>
```

now i've got this code:

```
$('div').on('mousedown','div',function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
    switch(e.which){
        //left mouse click
        case 1:
        break;
        //middle mouse click
        case 2: 
        break;
        //right mouse click
        case 3:
            console.log(e.target);
        break;
    }
});
```

With that code I can select the Container element and also the child elements by right click (the child elements will be created on runtime). but I want to be able to select the Parent element too. So can anyone give me an Advice how to fix that ?

Comment: `$(e.target).parent()`?

Comment: `$(this).parent()` doesn't work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to remove the 'div' filter.

```
$('div').on('mousedown',function(e){ ... }
```

Comment: well.. thats right ^^ I've tested that in another case before and I werent able to select the elements which are created on runtime, so I thought I have to add that too. But now it works.. dunno why :D..  thanks!